# Extract complete array from std class multi dimensional array php

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I am working on an exam system and I have run into a problem for getting the right result.
I want this result from answers array which match question ID 466

```
(
[id] => 234
[firstChoice] => 2
[choice] => 2
[marked] => 
[strikethrough] => Array()
[highlights] => 
[guessed] => 
[difficulty] => easy
[numTimesChanged] => 
[timeElapsed] => 36
)
```

I have this type of answers std class array.
I have same type of array for questions too.

```
Array(
[0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 234
        [firstChoice] => 2
        [choice] => 2
        [marked] => 
        [strikethrough] => Array
            (
            )

        [highlights] => 
        [guessed] => 
        [difficulty] => easy
        [numTimesChanged] => 
        [timeElapsed] => 36
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 466
        [firstChoice] => 3
        [choice] => 3
        [marked] => 
        [strikethrough] => Array
            (
            )

        [highlights] => 
        [guessed] => 
        [difficulty] => easy
        [numTimesChanged] => 
        [timeElapsed] => 5
    )
)
```

Comment: What have you _tried_?

Comment: I would recommend to set the id as a key at data generation, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = null;
foreach($array as $value){
    if($value->id == 466){
        $result = $value;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of your ID is not unique, you can use [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Solution :

```
<?php

$array = json_decode('[{"id":4,"data":"data1"},{"id":14,"data":"data41"},{"id":14,"data":"data14"}]');

$idSearched = 14;

function filter($item){
    global $idSearched;
    return $item->id === $idSearched;
}

$res = array_filter($array, "filter");
print_r($res);
```

[Live example](https://3v4l.org/bGpWF)